# Is there a (smart) way to send an array (intact!) via web form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

In PHP, I have an array. I would like to send all values in the array to the next page (result.php). When I receive the values in $_POST, can I get them in the array as they were? (or I can only get the values of the array separately or concatenated, and re-generate the array afterwards?)

I tried the following code, but it only concatenates the values in the array, so it is not satisfactory.

Please let me know what would be the best practice either way. Of course, I prefer to keep the original array intact!

Thank you!

```
<form class="form_container validationForm" action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="targetobject[]" value="
<?php $postvalue = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"););
foreach($postvalue as $value){echo $value;}
?>
">
<input type="text" class="form-control validationInput" name="search" placeholder="Type a search keyword"><br><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button></div></form>

//The following is result.php
<?php $targetobject = $_POST['targetobject'];
 echo var_dump($targetobject);
?>
```

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Volvo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "BMW"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Toyota"
}

Comment: That markup is not valid, is it?

Comment: This is a confusing question... I think what you're potentially missing is that, you want multiple `input`s, each with the name `targetobject[]` each with one of the values?

Comment: Might be simpler to string it along as JSON in a hidden input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put each value in a separate hidden `input` with a name containing `[]`. Try this :

```
 <form class="form_container validationForm" action="result.php" method="post">

 <?php $postvalue = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"]; ?>
 <?php foreach ($postvalue as $val) : ?>
     <input type="hidden" name="targetobject[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
 <?php endforeach; ?>  

 </form>

 <input type="text" class="form-control validationInput" name="search" placeholder="Type a search keyword"><br><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button></div></form>

 //The following is result.php
 <?php $targetobject = $_POST['targetobject'];
  echo var_dump($targetobject);
 ?>
```

Comment: This will blow up if you have some value containing a double quote

Comment: For normal cases, this is what I needed. @NicoHaase, Do you mean, if there is a string like "example", this solution does not work? Are there any other situations which may not work? What would be the solution to avoid this? Replacing "example" with example?

Comment: You should quote the output, for example using htmlentities

Comment: @NicoHasse, good catch. It's a must anytime you are echoing out stuff in HTML.

Comment: @NicoHasse, do you mean adding `htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you examine the HTTP result of the above suggestions, you'll see that they work by *repeating* the POST variable-names in an organized way.  And this approach is certainly not wrong.

Another way to do it is to send the data *JSON-encoded* as the value of a single field.  This approach allows truly-arbitrary data structures to be encoded and represented.  Essentially, though not quite, "classic AJAX."

So, "the choice is yours."

Answer (score 1):

Or with less letters:

```
<?php $postvalue = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); ?>

<form class="form_container validationForm" action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="targetobject" value='<?=json_encode( $postvalue ); ?>'>

<input type="text" class="form-control validationInput" name="search" placeholder="Type a search keyword"><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

//The following is result.php
<?php 
 $targetobject = json_decode( $_POST['targetobject'], $assoc = true );
 echo var_dump($targetobject);
?>
```